# Baggage transfer, Bahrain to Mauritius

Tags: tickets, luggage, mauritian-citizens

Hi I will be travelling from Bahrain to Dubai then Dubai to Bombay and Bombay to Mauritius. My e-ticket is individual one each I would like to ask do I have to get any visa and how to transfer the baggage. I am a Mauritian national

Comment: Which airline ? Also, you're asking two questions, it's best to ask them separately

Comment: You're saying that you've purchased three separate tickets, one for each leg?